# Datediff when time crosses midnight

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Any idea how to build datediff query that calculate time that possibly crosses midnight?

Of course, if that is one case, I would calculate separately part to and from midnight, but I need universal query, because I have thousands of rows, where some of them crosses midnight, and some not, and for every one of them I have to calc. datediff (which is up to 10 minutes, can't cross 2 days for that matter).

Comment: pls be clear ... what do you mean by time that crosses midnight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function handles both cases.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2011-12-20 11:43:00', '2011-12-20 11:50:00')
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2011-12-20 23:59:00', '2011-12-21 00:07:00')
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume begin_work = 20:00:00 
Assume end_work =   06:00:00 
ANSWER = 08:00:00

SELECT *,
CASE 
WHEN end_work > begin_work 
THEN timediff(end_work, begin_work) 
ELSE addtime(timediff('24:00:00',begin_work),end_work)
END AS elapsed_time 
FROM my_table

Limitation- this will only work for a time duration that does not exceed 23h 59m 59s.
If a time duration is over 24hrs I suggest using a DATEDIFF

Hope this helps,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are seeing is due to the datediff function looking at the values:

```
declare @start datetime = '2000-01-01 23:59:59.997'
declare @end datetime = '2000-01-02 00:00:01.003'

select datediff(mi,@start,@end) [mins], datediff(ss,@start,@end) [secs]

output:
mins    secs
1       2

select datediff(ss,@start,@end)/60 [mins], datediff(ms,@start,@end)/1000 [secs]

output:
mins    secs
0       1
```

The minute value does change. It wraps from 59 to 00 so the function correctly returns 1. To correctly calculate elapsed time I use seconds divided by 60 for minutes and milliseconds divided by 1000 for seconds. This prevents the crossing midnight issue. (note: 3 milliseconds is smallest granularity for time in SQL Server)